# using mongoose with nextjs

Tags: mongoose, next.js

I am trying to use mongoose to connect to a mongo db instance in a next.js app. I was following a blog post and they create a function to perform the connection but I am unsure of one line in particular. They create an async function `async function dbConnect` but then when connecting to mongoose they use `.then`. This doesn't make sense to me. If your function is async, why not use await instead? My question is if someone can expalin the following line of code and how you would rewrite using `await` instead:

```
cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then(mongoose => mongoose)
```

Here is the full file for reference

```
// /lib/dbConnect.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

/** 
Source : 
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose/utils/dbConnect.js 
**/


const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error(
    'Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local'
  )
}

/**
 * Global is used here to maintain a cached connection across hot reloads
 * in development. This prevents connections growing exponentially
 * during API Route usage.
 */
let cached = global.mongoose

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null }
}

async function dbConnect () {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      bufferCommands: false,
      bufferMaxEntries: 0,
      useFindAndModify: true,
      useCreateIndex: true
    }

    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then(mongoose => mongoose)
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise
  return cached.conn
}

export default dbConnect
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code example can be dramatically simplified to just this:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const { MONGO_URI } = process.env;

if (!MONGO_URI) throw new Error('MONGO_URI is not defined.');

let cached = global.mongoose;

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null };
}

export const dbConnect = async () => {

  if (cached.conn) return cached.conn;

  cached.conn = await mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI);
  
  return cached.conn;
}
```